# Perimeter of equilateral triangle from its area

Tags: triangles, area

In an exercise, I have to answer the perimeter of a equilateral triangle knowing that its area is $$\sqrt{3}$$

How can I achieve it? I tried inventing equations, but all dead ends.  Please explain.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the area of an equilateral triangle is given by $ \frac { \sqrt {3} } {4} l ^2$ where l is the length of a side?

Answer (score 3):

If an equilateral triangle has side length $d$, the length of every heigth is given by $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}d$ by the pythagorean theorem, hence the area is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}d^2$ and the perimeter is $3d$. Hence, if the area equals $\sqrt{3}$, the perimeter equals $6$.